# How can I lay two dataframes over another and keep all differing values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I want to join two dataframes keeping all differing values. 
Should be easy, but I did not find a related post in here.

```
DF1:
     0  1  2  3  4
0    0  0  0  0  1
1    0  0  0  0  1
2    0  0  0  0  1

DF2:
     0  1  2  3  4
0    0  0  2  0  0
1    0  0  2  0  0
2    0  0  2  0  0

Result:
     0  1  2  3  4
0    0  0  2  0  1
1    0  0  2  0  1
2    0  0  2  0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

If both have the same dimensions and are filled with zeros as in your example, you can simple sum them up

```
 df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = [[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1]])
 df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = [[0,2,0,0],[0,2,0,0]])
 df1 + df2

    0   1   2   3
    0   2   0   1
    0   2   0   1
```

But maybe you want a more flexible answer

Comment: do you know also how I can sum up only the cells which are in either one of the dataframes 0? I do not want to sum those up, in which in both cells already numbers > 0 exists.